# Use Javascript to match elements with a class pattern

Tags: javascript

Hi I have a number of elements:

```
<div data-stage-1="hello">Hello</div>
<div data-stage-2="hello">Hello</div>
<div data-stage-3="hello">Hello</div>
```

Using Javascript how would i pull these elements into an array by matching their similar data attributes? (Not the 'hello', but the 'data-stage-x')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be able to use the `attributes` property of the `<div>` element.  The following is untested...

```
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
for (var i=0; i<divs.length; i++) {
  var d = divs[i];
  // Loop over attributes and check their names...
  for (var a=0; a<d.attributes.length; a++) {
    if (d.attributes[a].name.indexOf("data-stage-") === 0) {
       // it's a match...
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I think `d.attributes[a].indexOf` might need to be `d.attributes[a].name.indexOf`, otherwise great answer.

Comment: @Colin Thanks. I was just setting up a test instance to find the correct property there. You saved me a minute or two